# Difference between rm and rm -rf

Tags: linux

I am fairly new to linux and I found this command 'rm -rf' which is confusing. I wanted to know whats the difference between 'rm' and 'rm -rf' and when should those be used?

Comment: A good command to know when new to linux is `man`, in this case `man rm`.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/rm

Comment: http://superuser.com

Comment: Generally speaking, the major difference is that one day you will regret using `rm -rf`. It's very, very easy for a typo to wipe your entire system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rm). `rm` removes files and -rf are to options: `-r` remove directories and their contents **recursively**, `-f` ignore nonexistent files, never prompt.

Comment: what does "ignore nonexistent files" mean? shouldn't nonexistent files not be an issue anyways?

Answer (score 7):

rm is the same as "del".  It deletes the specified file.  It will not delete directories.  It will also warn you about deleting some files.

rm -rf adds the "recursive" and "force" flags.  It will remove the specified file and silently ignore any warnings when doing so.  If it is a directory, it will remove the directory and all its contents, including subdirectories.

Answer (score 4):

If **`foo`** is a directory

then **`rm foo`** will return an error

but **`rm -rf foo`** will remove the directory, and remove all files and subdirectories below that directory.

Comment: thanks I was wondering what would happen if you `rm` a directory without the `-r` flag, would it leave the contents and subdirectories there like ghosts but then you couldnt access them but then would they take up space on your computer still what a nightmare or would it just remove it all but then like the only way to do that is recursively so whats the point of the `-r` tag

Comment: @cmarangu:  i think of it this way: `rm` command removes a file; the `rmdir` command removes an empty directory.  everything else is gravy.  what if i have a directory with a bunch of files and subdirectories below it... i need to run `rm` on the files, and on an empty subdirectory, i can run an `rmdir`.  The point of the `rm -r` option is that I can quickly remove a non-empty directory with one command, in one fell swoop. https://superuser.com/questions/1224758/why-does-rm-not-remove-directories

Comment: @cmarangu:  if we atttempt to "`rm foo`: where `foo` is a *directory*, we will get an error back, and directory `foo` is not removed or modified. if we want to remove a directory, we would use the "`rmdir`" command.

Comment: oh ok. but then why isnt it `rmdir -r` if there are other directories in it and why isnt it `rmfile` and why is it `touch` for creating a new file it makes no sense at al

Comment: why is it all BA.sh and CLang and who made up the acronym they are like a jester